# ArcGIS License Manager update fail

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager, arcgis-10.6, windows-server-2012

I have a problem with update my ArcGIS license manager from ver. 10.5 to 10.6. LM runs on separate virtual machine. My Desktop cannot connect to LM server after update. I've tried to update LM on 2012R2 Standard (x64).

Comment: There are changes at 10.5.1 (and 10.6 client) so if your likely to need this http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/license-manager/latest/license-manager-installation-and-startup.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E84393E22BFC44B28C469B80369BC746

Answer (score 1):

Since your LM is on a 2012 R2 Server you should check you IP settings and firewall. On the client ping the server and then from the server ping itself. If they don't match (one shows IPv4 and the other IPv6) then you have found the problem.

Secondly, with Server 2012 R2 they implemented Microsoft Firewalls by default so you should check your ports. If you locked a port to the flexLM exe files, remember your base path the exe's has changed to C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\License10.6\bin from \License10.5

Rich D, GISP